# Is it possible to do a partially collapsing sidebar in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a Bootstrap page which will have a sidebar which partially collapses on scroll ... it should collapse to a narrower version of itself ( eg icons instead of text style ) and this collapse would take place on scroll, and then could be opened up to it's full width by clicking an element.

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how I would make this work while taking bootstrap into consideration, because for a widescreen the sidebar would need to be fixed at the far left ( or right ) ... ie not part of the boostrap section ... whereas for a tablet view for instance I presume that the sidebar would need to take up one or more of the columns ( or else I would need to adjust the body padding on the entire page), which I could do but I am hoping there are some tried and tested methods. I feel certain that I've seen this technique used but I can't find an example of it. Does anyone know how to get around the problem, or whether it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    .....
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar{
  width: 100px;  
}
```

This will toggle the sidebar's width on window scroll. You can also add the window scroll's function to sidebar mouse click event listener.

Comment: Thanks ... although I think it works better with addClass, and also there seems to be a bug ( shouldn't #wrapper.active sidebar be #wrapper.active #sidebar?  ... you might want to edit your answer ) [here's](http://www.bootply.com/133596#) my bootply ... but really my question was more about how to handle the narrow sidebar overlaying the bootstrap content while displayed on a narrow device. Since I made this post I've decided to flip it to top navigation when used on tablet/phone.

Comment: Thanks for noting the bug here. addClass was ok, but for each scroll, I just toggled the div. You can do as per your wish. Can't you use bootstrap's [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Comment: Yes I know ... I just found it hard to visualize how I would get the sidebar to play with the grid system. I'm not sure it's practical. I can't find an example of what I'm after anywhere. I think the only answer is to create margins on the side of the narrow format grid system to hold the collapsed sidebar, like [this](http://demo.cloudworkthemes.com/rite/) ... but I was hoping to avoid that. No worries anyway like I said I'll just use top navigation for tablets and below.